# Cómo pasar una llave foranea de un formulario a otro Django

Tags: django, template, vistas

Estoy empezando a trabajar con **Django** y me parece que es una maravilla de la cual estoy aprendiendo.

Estoy haciendo una aplicación para facturar producto y para ello tengo tres modelos: Factura, Detalle Factura y Producto.

Tengo un `template` en donde muestro los datos de la factura y abajo el detalle. Para agregar productos al detalle tengo un botón "Añadir" que al presionar abre un formulario para agregar los productos pero tengo que seleccionar la factura en el `comboBox` del detalle y yo no quiero eso, lo que necesito es que automáticamente aparezca seleccionada la factura e inclusive que ni siguiera aparezca el `comboBox` pero que sin embargo al presionar guardar se añada al detalle de la factura.

Agradeceré todo ayuda.

**Modelo Factura (Pedido)**

```
class Pedido(models.Model):
    cliente = models.ForeignKey(Cliente, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='clienteventa')
    fecha = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    bordado = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null = True, blank = True, default=Decimal('0.00'))
    estado_pedido = models.ForeignKey(EstadoPedido, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '{} {} {}'.format(self.cliente.nombre, " - fecha: ", self.fecha)
```

**Modelo Detalle (Detalle Pedido)**

```
class DetallePedido(models.Model):
    pedido = models.ForeignKey(Pedido, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='pedidodetalle')
    cojin = models.ForeignKey(Cojin, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='cojindetalle')
    precio = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null = True, blank = True, default=Decimal('0.00'))
    cantidad = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    descuento = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null = True, blank = True, default=Decimal('0.00'))

    def get_venta(self):
        return (self.precio  * self.cantidad) - self.descuento
```

**Template** en donde muestro el Pedido y Detalle
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Vista** que genera el template anterior

```
class ListarDtPedido(DetailView):
    model = Pedido
    template_name = 'pedidos/listar_pedido_detalle.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ListarDtPedido, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['detalle'] = DetallePedido.objects.filter(pedido = context['object'])
        return context
```

Comment: ¿Generas el formulario automáticamente? Porque puedes editarlo y eliminar los componentes que quieras. No tienes que elegir la factura, porque puedes asignarle el valor de `pedido.id` y hacer el campo tipo `hidden`.

Comment: Perfecto, gracias por tu apoyo. Lo que hice fue agregar en el contexto el formulario del detalle y oculté el campo de la factura, de esta forma cuando presiono en añadir me aparece el formulario del detalle en la misma factura  y por medio de post le envío los datos al formulario de la vista.

Comment: Pero donde se asigna el valor de pedido.id? en la vista o en el formulario?