# Pasar una llave Foránea un Formulario

Tags: django, django-forms

Tengo dos tablas

```
class Afiliado(models.Model):          
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Pago(models.Model): # Tabla Cabecera de Pago        
    afiliado = models.ForeignKey(Afiliado, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fecha_pago = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

este es mi formulario para agregar los pagos:

```
class RegistroPago(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Pago
        fields = [ 
            'afiliado' ,          
            'fecha_pago',            
        ]
        labels = {     

            'afiliado':'Nombre del Afiliado',
            'fecha_pago':'Fecha de Pago',             
        }
        widgets = {
            'afiliado': forms.HiddenInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'fecha_pago': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),                        
        }
```

[lista de afiliados](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syDQM.png)

[Detalle afiliado](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Hflf.png)

[Formulario de Pagos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qZum.png)

Por favor alguien me pude orientar como hago para pasarle el id del afiliado al formulario para que lo relacione directamente.

en esta pregunta que es similar [Cómo pasar una llave foranea de un formulario a otro Django](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/90305/c%C3%B3mo-pasar-una-llave-foranea-de-un-formulario-a-otro-django)
un usuario le responde que se puede Hacer el campo tipo **hidden** y que puedes asignarle el valor de afiliado.id, ya lo del campo hice lo hice lo que quiero saber como y en donde puedo asignarle ese valor, ahí puse unas imágenes no se si me hago entender disculpen.

```
class PagoCreate(CreateView):
    model = Pago
    form_class = RegistroPago
    template_name = 'crear_pago.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('lista_pagos')
```

mi Template :

```
{% extends 'base/base.html' %}

{% block content%}

<title>
    {% block title %}Crear Pago{% endblock %}
</title>

 <div class="container">
      <div class="header clearfix">      

<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
  <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:white;">
    {{ form.as_p }}
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Guardar</button>  
  <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" href="/pago" role="button" >Cancelar</a>
</form>
    </div>
</div>      
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trata pasandole el pk del Afiliado en la url a la vista de crear, ejemplo:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:id_afiliado>', views.PagoCreate.as_view(), name='nombre'),
]
```

Luego en el view.py quedaria algo como lo siguiente:

```
class PagoCreate(CreateView):
    model = Pago
    form_class = RegistroPago
    template_name = 'crear_pago.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('lista_pagos')  

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super().get_initial()
        initial['afiliado'] = self.kwargs['id_afiliado']
        return initial
```

Comment: hola buenas tardes, esto es exactamente lo que quería hacer! de verdad muchas gracias por tomarse el tiempo de responder, ahora cuando selecciono un afiliado para crearle su pago ya en el formulario me aparece y oculto el campo como me dijo @Jota con: afiliado = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())

Comment: pues de nada para eso estamos, igual puedes agradecerme marcando la respuesta como aceptada o votando :)

Answer (score 1):

Tu formulario quedaría así:

```
class RegistroPago(forms.ModelForm):
    afiliado = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    fecha_pago = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Pago
        fields = ['fecha_pago']
```

No es necesario indicarle clase CSS alguna, pues va a estar oculto.
Posteriormente en el `views.py` le seteas el valor del ID del afiliado al formulario con:

```
form = RegistroPago(initial={'afiliado': id_afiliado})
```

Comment: muchas gracias por su respuesta, la linea que tengo que agregar a mi vista va dentro de una función especifica? porque la coloco al principio o al final y me dice: NameError: name 'id_afiliado' is not defined

Comment: Con id_afiliado me refería a que tienes que pasarle ahí el ID del afiliado al cual quieres asignarle un pago, evidentemente esa variable tu no la tienes... era solo un ejemplo.

Comment: esta linea: form = RegistroPago(initial={'afiliado': id_afiliado})  la puse dentro de una función get_context_data dentro de PagoCreateView, si yo declaro por ejemplo: id_afiliado = 1, cuando se carga el formulario  efectivamente se setea automáticamente el afiliado con ese numero de id. Hay alguna manera de que sea dinámica esta variable es decir que me la traiga automáticamente?